# Finding hard-coded IP addresses using Visual Studio 2010 'Find in Files' utility (Ctrl+Shift+F)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ip-address

I need to find all hard-coded IP addresses in some of our Visual Studio 2010 solutions.

How would I do this using the standard 'Find' utility (Ctrl+Shift+F) from Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Do a "find using regex," and supply it with a regex that matches the four-octet pattern of IP addresses.

Comment: Ok. I will try this: \b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately the regex search in Visual Studio 2010's "find in files" functionality is not Perl5-compatible.  This regex pattern will match any numbers specified in a `x.x.x.x` style (ie. an IPv4-style address):

```
[0-9]#\.[0-9]#\.[0-9]#\.[0-9]#
```

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VS.REGULAREXPRESSIONBUILDER%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true), it doesn't look like there's a way to specify that a pattern must be repeated *between 1 and 3 times* which is what you really want for the IPv4-style octets, so the above pattern will also match version numbers like `2.0.20505.0`.

You can, however, limit the number of digits in the octets to 3 by specifying them explicitly as separate groups, although it gets very verbose:

```
([0-9]|([0-9][0-9])|([0-9][0-9][0-9]))\.([0-9]|([0-9][0-9])|([0-9][0-9][0-9]))\.([0-9]|([0-9][0-9])|([0-9][0-9][0-9]))\.([0-9]|([0-9][0-9])|([0-9][0-9][0-9]))
```

This will still match version numbers with 3 or fewer digits per "section" of the version, like `4.0.0.0`, but it will also match IPv4 addresses like `11.2.123.21`.

The format for writing IPv6 addresses is more flexible than for IPv4 and while it's probably possible to match them with a Visual Studio 2010 regex, it would be horribly complicated.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

For **Visual studio 2017** this regex worked fine for me: `((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)`

Comment: thank you for your pattern. It however returns many false positives in my project, including hexadecimal values :). They seem to go away by inserting "#\" right before ".){3}" like so ((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)#\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?). I have not verified it works yet.